# Can't attach animationClip to animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I manage to get an animationClip from my animator. But when I try to attach the animationClip to the animation it fails.

I am not sure why

```
public AnimationClip GetAnimationClip(string name)
     {
         if (!anim)
             return null;

         foreach (AnimationClip clip in anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips) {
             if (clip.name == name)
                 return clip;
         }

         return null;
     }
```

This part works fine, as evidenced by the following

[image: animationClip fails to attach to animation]

Here is the part that fails

```
 if (ready) {
             for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
             {
                 if (player1Attacks [j] == 1) {
                     animationClip = GetAnimationClip("Armature|HAttack1");
                     animation.AddClip(animationClip, "HA1");
                     animation.PlayQueued ("HA1", QueueMode.PlayNow);
                 }
```

The " `animation.AddClip(animationClip, "HA1");` " is the part that is failing.

As you can see from the image above, the animation clip is found but it does not manage to attach to the animation.

Why?

Whole code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

    Animator anim;
    public AnimationClip animationClip;
    public Animation animation;
    int[] player1Attacks;
    int[] player1Defences;

    GameObject g;

    bool ready;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        animationClip = GetComponent<AnimationClip>();
        g = new GameObject ();
        g.AddComponent<Animation>();
        animation = GetComponent<Animation>();



        player1Attacks = new int[9];

        ready = false;


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (New.done == true) 
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                player1Attacks [i] = New.actions [i]; ready = true;
            }
        }

        if (ready) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) 
            {
                if (player1Attacks [j] == 1) {
                    animationClip = GetAnimationClip("Armature|HAttack1");
                    animation.AddClip(animationClip, "HA1");
                    animation.PlayQueued ("HA1", QueueMode.PlayNow);
                }




            }
        }

    }

    public AnimationClip GetAnimationClip(string name)
    {
        if (!anim)
            return null;

        foreach (AnimationClip clip in anim.runtimeAnimatorController.animationClips) {
            if (clip.name == name)
                return clip;
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the
>   "Player1" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You
>   probably need to add a Animation to the game object "Player1". Or your
>   script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

Unity is telling you where and why something went bad you didn't pay attention to that.

You mentioned it is this part `animation.AddClip(animationClip, "HA1");` which is correct.

It is very likely you have `animation = GetComponent<Animation>();` in your code before calling `animation.AddClip(animationClip, "HA1");`.

That error means that `GetComponent<Animation>();` failed because there is no `Animation` component attached to your Script.

You must attach `Animation` to the-same GameObject `Player1` script is attached to before you can call `GetComponent<Animation>();`. When it fails, animation becomes `null` which means that you can't call any of its function.

You can also attach `Animation` from code instead of Editor with `gameObject.AddComponent<Animation>();`

Now you can get component and add clip.

```
animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
animation.AddClip(animationClip, "HA1");
```

**EDIT**:

After updating your updated code:

You are currently adding the `Animation` component to **g** GameObject so you must get component from **g** GameObject not from `this.gameObject`.

Change `animation = GetComponent<Animation>();` to `animation = g.GetComponent<Animation>();`.

Comment: I created a new animation object and I am trying to attach it, but it doesn't seem possible. Not from editor.  If my script is attached to Player1 how would I attach animation from code ?

Comment: @DragonCoder That doesn't make sense. You don't create new Animation. You add component with `AddComponent` or from the Editor then access it `GetComponent<Animation>();`. Read my answer again. If you have further question, post your complete script. `AnimationClip` is fine but `Animation` is not. Its needs to be initialized.

Comment: @DragonCoder Look at my Edit.

Comment: It worked, but now I have other errors : "Assets/PlayerScript.cs(23,28): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.AddComponent(System.Type)'"  + "The animation state HA1 could not be played because it couldn't be found!
Please attach an animation clip with the name 'HA1' or call this function only for existing animations."

Comment: @DragonCoder What error? The error in your original question is gone? Correct?

Comment: Yes, but this 2 errors appeared : "Assets/PlayerScript.cs(23,28): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.GameObject.AddComponent(System.Type)'" + "The animation state HA1 could not be played because it couldn't be found! Please attach an animation clip with the name 'HA1' or call this function only for existing animations."

Comment: @DragonCoder Change all the imported `Animation` Type to `legacy` http://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/MecanimLegacyRigTab.png

Comment: I did it. Should I reimport the objects ? Both errors still there.

Comment: @DragonCoder Yes, re-import it and set it to legacy. Also what is your **g** object used for?